# Cannot see console.log-s in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, console.log

I can't remember when it started happening but basically as the title says I can't see `console.log`-s on my app but the states are getting updated because the app is working properly. And then if I update something in the code anything at all and the app recompiles I suddenly see everything that I logged before and after the second recompile. It happens across all of my app components.
Even the errors I receive just say where the error is and not what it is. I tried taking out component by component in hopes that the logs will start appearing but the problem persists.

```
console.log("something")
```

[image]

```
console.log("something")
console.log("something else")
```

[image]

Here is a purposely created error to simulate the problem
[image]

Hope someone can help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have an active filter, remove that and you should be good to go.

[Current active filter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9W2bj.png)

Comment: yea tnx i feel really studin now

Answer (score 1):

You have the console filter set [image]

Answer (score 0):

Check the console filters.
For some reason it happens like this...
[image: see image]